# Android Custom Spinner with TimePicker

Tags: android, spinner

I have created a custom `Spinner` with a dropdown list, in which the first items are known times, and the last item gives the user the possibility to open a `TimePicker` to choose a time.

**What I have achieved so far:**

I can use the custom spinner to choose the first items, and for the last item, the click on it shows the TimePicker Dialog.

**What I want to do:**

I have some problems setting the selection when I choose the last item.

When the dropdown is closed, **I want to "show" in the `Spinner` the time selected by the user** from the picker when choosing the last item.

Here's a portion of my custom Spinner code :

```
@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    if (position == getAdapter().getCount() - 1) {
        // last item
        openTimePicker();
    } else {
        super.setSelection(position);
    }
}

private void openTimePicker() {
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: at which position you want to show the `time` in the spinner? also post the code where you're setting the spinner in adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get TimePicker value and add to Adapter Spinner and refresh spinner.

```
String strDateTime = timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" +          timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    spinnerAdapter.add(strDateTime);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this help!